# Install libraries on R terminal

Tags: r, install.packages

I've uploaded my R code on the company's server in order to run it. It was running smoothly on my local R studio and now when I try to run it with Rscript my_script.r I get an enormous amount of errors when trying to install very basic libraries.

```
if (!require("ggrepel")) {
    install.packages("ggrepel", repos="http://cran.fhcrc.org")
    library(ggrepel)
}

if (!require("ggplot2")) {
    install.packages("ggplot2", repos="http://cran.fhcrc.org")
    library("ggplot2")
}

if (!require("gridExtra")) {
    install.packages("gridExtra", repos="http://cran.fhcrc.org")
    library("gridExtra")
}
```

This is my code to install the libraries and here's the error:

```
Loading required package: ggrepel
Installing package into ‘/home/yoda/Rlibs’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘tibble’, ‘ggplot2’

trying URL 'http://cran.fhcrc.org/src/contrib/tibble_1.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 54517 bytes (53 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 53 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.fhcrc.org/src/contrib/ggplot2_2.2.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2213308 bytes (2.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.1 MB

trying URL 'http://cran.fhcrc.org/src/contrib/ggrepel_0.6.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 568599 bytes (555 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 555 KB

* installing *source* package ‘tibble’ ...
** package ‘tibble’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c matrixToDataFrame.cpp -o matrixToDataFrame.o
matrixToDataFrame.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Rcpp::List copy_columns(const Rcpp::Matrix<RTYPE>&) [with int RTYPE = 10; Rcpp::List = Rcpp::Vector<19>]’:
matrixToDataFrame.cpp:91:48:   required from here
matrixToDataFrame.cpp:71:41: error: no type named ‘ConstColumn’ in ‘class Rcpp::Matrix<10>’
     typename Matrix<RTYPE>::ConstColumn column( m.column(j) ) ;
                                         ^
matrixToDataFrame.cpp:71:41: error: no type named ‘ConstColumn’ in ‘class Rcpp::Matrix<10>’
matrixToDataFrame.cpp:71:41: error: no type named ‘ConstColumn’ in ‘class Rcpp::Matrix<10>’
matrixToDataFrame.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Rcpp::List copy_columns(const Rcpp::Matrix<RTYPE>&) [with int RTYPE = 13; Rcpp::List = Rcpp::Vector<19>]’:
matrixToDataFrame.cpp:92:48:   required from here
matrixToDataFrame.cpp:71:41: error: no type named ‘ConstColumn’ in ‘class Rcpp::Matrix<13>’
matrixToDataFrame.cpp:71:41: error: no type named ‘ConstColumn’ in ‘class Rcpp::Matrix<13>’
matrixToDataFrame.cpp:71:41: error: no type named ‘ConstColumn’ in ‘class Rcpp::Matrix<13>’
matrixToDataFrame.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Rcpp::List copy_columns(const Rcpp::Matrix<RTYPE>&) [with int RTYPE = 14; Rcpp::List = Rcpp::Vector<19>]’:
matrixToDataFrame.cpp:93:49:   required from here
matrixToDataFrame.cpp:71:41: error: no type named ‘ConstColumn’ in ‘class Rcpp::Matrix<14>’
matrixToDataFrame.cpp:71:41: error: no type named ‘ConstColumn’ in ‘class Rcpp::Matrix<14>’
matrixToDataFrame.cpp:71:41: error: no type named ‘ConstColumn’ in ‘class Rcpp::Matrix<14>’
matrixToDataFrame.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Rcpp::List copy_columns(const Rcpp::Matrix<RTYPE>&) [with int RTYPE = 15; Rcpp::List = Rcpp::Vector<19>]’:
matrixToDataFrame.cpp:94:49:   required from here
matrixToDataFrame.cpp:71:41: error: no type named ‘ConstColumn’ in ‘class Rcpp::Matrix<15>’
matrixToDataFrame.cpp:71:41: error: no type named ‘ConstColumn’ in ‘class Rcpp::Matrix<15>’
matrixToDataFrame.cpp:71:41: error: no type named ‘ConstColumn’ in ‘class Rcpp::Matrix<15>’
matrixToDataFrame.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Rcpp::List copy_columns(const Rcpp::Matrix<RTYPE>&) [with int RTYPE = 16; Rcpp::List = Rcpp::Vector<19>]’:
matrixToDataFrame.cpp:95:48:   required from here
matrixToDataFrame.cpp:71:41: error: no type named ‘ConstColumn’ in ‘class Rcpp::Matrix<16>’
matrixToDataFrame.cpp:71:41: error: no type named ‘ConstColumn’ in ‘class Rcpp::Matrix<16>’
matrixToDataFrame.cpp:71:41: error: no type named ‘ConstColumn’ in ‘class Rcpp::Matrix<16>’
matrixToDataFrame.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Rcpp::List copy_columns(const Rcpp::Matrix<RTYPE>&) [with int RTYPE = 19; Rcpp::List = Rcpp::Vector<19>]’:
matrixToDataFrame.cpp:96:48:   required from here
matrixToDataFrame.cpp:71:41: error: no type named ‘ConstColumn’ in ‘class Rcpp::Matrix<19>’
matrixToDataFrame.cpp:71:41: error: no type named ‘ConstColumn’ in ‘class Rcpp::Matrix<19>’
matrixToDataFrame.cpp:71:41: error: no type named ‘ConstColumn’ in ‘class Rcpp::Matrix<19>’
make: *** [matrixToDataFrame.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘tibble’
* removing ‘/home/yoda/Rlibs/tibble’
ERROR: dependency ‘tibble’ is not available for package ‘ggplot2’
* removing ‘/home/yoda/Rlibs/ggplot2’
* installing *source* package ‘ggrepel’ ...
** package ‘ggrepel’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c repel_boxes.cpp -o repel_boxes.o
g++ -m64 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -Wl,-z,relro -o ggrepel.so RcppExports.o repel_boxes.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/yoda/Rlibs/ggrepel/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error : package ‘ggplot2’ 1.0.1 was found, but >= 2.0.0 is required by ‘ggrepel’
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘ggrepel’
* removing ‘/home/yoda/Rlibs/ggrepel’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpukzDll/downloaded_packages’
Error in library(ggrepel) : there is no package called ‘ggrepel’
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘ggrepel’
2: In install.packages("ggrepel", repos = "http://cran.fhcrc.org") :
  installation of package ‘tibble’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("ggrepel", repos = "http://cran.fhcrc.org") :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("ggrepel", repos = "http://cran.fhcrc.org") :
  installation of package ‘ggrepel’ had non-zero exit status
Execution halted
```

I have no idea what's going on, and I have to submit this. Is there any way without having sudo rights to download and install an R package?

Comment: Try installing a newer version of Rcpp first; ConstColumn was added a few releases ago.

Comment: @nrussell I could kiss you right now, if that's not offensive to you <3

Comment: And, there is a way of installing without rights, most of the time companies leave the temp folder open. Try installing it in there, then point R to it.